# slam_toolbox + LD19 LIDAR

Tags: slam, lidar, ros2

I recently purchased the LIDAR LD19. I managed to configure it and it is working fine, presenting the data in the RVIZ (LaserScan).

The LIDAR node is configured as described at: https://github.com/Myzhar/ldrobot-lidar-ros2/. Below I have a photo of the LIDAR LD19 presenting the Laserscan on the Rviz.

[image: LIDAR LD19 presenting the Laserscan on the Rviz]

My question is: I would like to make a SLAM process and for that I am using the slam_toolbox framework (ROS2 Humble). I set up slam_toolbox following a tutorial and apparently managed to subscribe to the /ldlidar_node/scan thread. As shown in the image below.

[image: Photo of terminal output]

To configure slam_toolbox I used the yaml file described at: https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/ros2/launch/online_async_launch.py

I opened RVIZ2, activated the map. I added the map topic, but I can't generate the map (SLAM) at all. The funny thing is that apparently ldlidar_node is being processed  by slam_toolbox (you can see in the terminal that it is subscribed to the topic). But the map is not generated.

Could you let me know if LD-19 Lidar is compatible with ROS2 slam_toolbox? Is there any other framework, compatible, that I can generate the SLAM?

Comment: Instead of a blurry photo of terminal output, it is better to paste the *actual text* of the terminal output in to your question, and use the code formatting. Photos are not text-searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the `slam_toolbox` recently but it is probably something with your TF-Tree. You can see the tree in `rqt` and then open the *tf tree plugin* under *visualization*, I think.

There should be an `odom` link with an arrow to `base_link`. If not you haven't configured your odometry correctly. I think you can also configure the `slam_toolbox` to publish the `map` to `base_link` transform directly. But this is not recommended. See [REP 105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html).

Just searching for the message in your terminal:

- [[slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'](https://answers.ros.org/question/389383/slam_toolbox-message-filter-dropping-message-for-reason-discarding-message-because-the-queue-is-full/)
- [Slam Toolbox: Message Filter dropping message for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'](https://answers.ros.org/question/393773/slam-toolbox-message-filter-dropping-message-for-reason-discarding-message-because-the-queue-is-full/)
- [Slam_toolbox "discarding message because the queue is full" on a Jetson Xavier.](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/issues/465)